# What was Borges referring to when he said “I have known what the Greeks do not know, incertitude.”?

Tags: greeks

Taken from opening paragraph of *Labyrinths*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. One-line posts are discouraged because it is hard to tell from them what people are looking for. It is also unclear that this is a question about philosophy in a more academic sense, as understood on this site. 
[Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask.

Comment: isn't labyrinths a collection?  what particular story is it from?

Comment: This sentence is not from the opening paragraph of Labyrinths. It's from the opening paragraph of the third short story, "The Lottery in Babylon.” It is spoken by that story's narrator. The incertitude is a function of the fantastic social/government system that story characterizes. Since, in it, people are rotated through stations or roles in life, it's impossible for them to know what their future holds. Hence, incertitude. This is a literary interpretation question.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this line is open to interpretation. One interpretation might be that he's denying excluded middle. But he would probably claim to be anti-logic (which of course to a logician is incoherent). At the least, the Greeks believed in the concept of truth, and (probably) that there is such a thing. You don't have to read much Borges to get the sense he doesn't believe in truth in this sense, that is, in bivalent truth.